# Build .NET Core Applications with an Agent, that can't connect to the internet

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore

I have some trouble configuring / setting up the VSTS Agent and the TFS to be able to build .NET Core without connecting to the Internet.

Our build clients/agents currently are by security design not able to connect to the internet. That is a problem, because .NET Core seems to have a lot of packages, that are being retrieved from Nuget. Even the standard things like `System.Runtime.Loader`, which I have know knowledge of on what it does. But I think it's just a standard microsoft library that is needed by .NET Core and automatically added when creating a project right?

Anyways, back to the problem: Whenever I try to restore a project, it of course fails with something like this:

```
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (>= 2.1.2)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc (>= 2.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 2.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy (>= 2.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets (>= 2.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Runtime.Loader (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Net.Requests (>= 4.0.11)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Net.NameResolution (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Data.Common (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Threading.Thread (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Xml.XmlDocument (>= 4.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource (>= 4.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.StackTrace (>= 4.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http (>= 1.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'NLog.Extensions.Logging (>= 1.3.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions (>= 1.1.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
```

I think I have a solution, but I don't like it at all: I could make a nuget feed to include every single package, that is required by my application.

But what I'd like to know, isn't there any other way to make this work? I don't like the idea of always having to upload/update all these standard .NET Core nuget packages all the time.

It would be nice to only have the real third party libraries like NLog / EF in the feed...

**Edit:**

**What I don't understand, why doesn't the vsts-agent not use the folder:**

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder
```

Comment: Could your `NuGetFallbackFolder` be corrupt by any chance? I've heard that deleting it and then restoring again has worked for some people.